# Has anyone built an rs232 to usb converter?

Tags: usb, serial, rs232, converter, diy

I want to implement serial communication into one of my projects, but I'm hesitant to use a serial cable due them them being exceedingly hard to find nowadays.  I found an old converter and took it apart to see whats inside it, and to my surprise, they were all components I already own (basically). Just a pic microcontroller (a really old one which I don't own), and a level converter (not the max232 which I have).  Are there any tutorials that include code that would explain how to build one of these from scratch?

Comment: Get an FTDI chip and something similar to `max232` for level shifting. These two plus couple of capacitors will do the job. No code needed.

Comment: Or if you just want a USB port on your board, no level shifting is actually needed, so just FTDI..

Comment: A 1 dollar usb to TTL serial converter would be the best choice for a project. If you really want to go about it, Microchip has a USB to CDC/Serial framework for their usb enabled Pic processors. And there are open source framework/libraries for the same on ATTiny/ATmegas and msp430 and other chips.

Comment: A serial cable may be hard to find, but easy to build. Get two D-SUB-9 connectors and solder them onto a suitable cable.

Comment: @Ariser It is much harder to find a serial port :)

Comment: 9 pin serial "COM" ports are surprisingly common even today. Modern motherboards will tend have them on a header than out as a connector but they are still there most of the tiem. The cables themselves are easy to find.

Comment: DIY usb-cdc projects are not worth it for windows targets without custom drivers, which make it out of reach for most people. Google 'usb cdc windows bug' or similar. Usb-hid is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I use [this part](https://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/USBtoUARTBridgeVCPDrivers.aspx) in a lot of my products. It creates a virtual com port (essentially this chip is what is inside a converter cable but this way your product still has a normal USB connector).

The above is just one example. I'm sure there are other similar parts out there.

Comment: You misunderstand. The OP isn't looking for an easy, practical solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's true... It said he wanted what's inside a converter to put into what he already called a project.

Answer (score 0):

FTDI's [DB9-USB modules](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Modules/USBRSxxx.htm#DB9-USB) provide a USB-serial adapter in the same form factor as a conventional DB9 connector, allowing you to place either in the final product in order to meet requirements.